# Gulpfile isn't watching files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

For some reason when I use the "gulp" command it's not "watching" at the end.  I want it to refresh the page when I make changes to the files.  Here is my gulpfile:

```
//Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'),

//Plugins
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 concat = require('gulp-concat'),
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
 rename = require('gulp-rename'),
 fileInclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
 imageMin = require('gulp-imagemin');

//Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        style: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/css'))
});

//Concatenate and minify the Js Plugins
gulp.task('jsplugins', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/assets/js/plugins/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('plugins.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js'))
        .pipe(rename('plugins.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js/'));
});

//Minify main JS
gulp.task('jsmain', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/assets/js/main.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js'));
});

//Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/assets/images/**.*')
        .pipe(imageMin({progressive: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/images/'))
});

//Includes
gulp.task('fileInclude', function() {
  gulp.src(['source/*.html'])
    .pipe(fileInclude({prefix: '@@',basepath: '@file'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});

//Main Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('source/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('source/*.html', ['fileInclude']);
    gulp.watch('source/assets/js/main.js', ['jsmain']);
    gulp.watch('source/assets/js/plugins/*.js', ['jsplugins']);
    gulp.watch('source/assets/images/**.*', ['images']);
});

//Main Command
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'jsplugins','jsmain', 'images','fileInclude', 'watch'], function() {
    process.exit(0);
});
```

And here's the output i'm getting when running "gulp":

```
[09:57:44] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/elonco-35359-LOOC-Art-Manage-
Kit/gulpfile.js
[09:57:44] Starting 'sass'...
[09:57:44] Starting 'jsplugins'...
[09:57:44] Starting 'jsmain'...
[09:57:44] Starting 'images'...
[09:57:44] Starting 'fileInclude'...
[09:57:44] Finished 'fileInclude' after 3.1 ms
[09:57:44] Starting 'watch'...
[09:57:44] Finished 'watch' after 21 ms
[09:57:44] Finished 'jsplugins' after 52 ms
[09:57:45] Finished 'jsmain' after 131 ms
[09:57:45] Finished 'sass' after 163 ms
[09:57:45] gulp-imagemin: Minified 2 images (saved 5.27 kB - 44.4%)
[09:57:45] Finished 'images' after 178 ms
[09:57:45] Starting 'default'...
```

I'm not sure why the watch isn't running at the end.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, what gulp version are you running?

Comment: @kot I'm using gulp version 3.9.0

Comment: actually the way your following is correct only...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  For some reason it was actually watching but appeared not to be.  Not sure why that happened at first.  It may have been another plugin that I have since removed.